# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Character,Integer>

Tags: eclipse, java-8, java-stream

Trying to get mapping digit between 1-26 from input String using stream operation.
input - 
    XYZ or xyz
expected output is Map -
    X - 24
    Y - 25
    Z - 26

Below logic is giving compilation error :

```
 Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String testString = scr.next();
    Map<Character, Integer> charDigitMap = testString.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect( Collectors.toMap(c -> c ,c -> (c - 'A' + 1))); 
charDigitMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("--"+k+"--"+v));
```

Error is :
Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<Character,Integer>`

P.S : 
Looks its a eclipse issue. Working fine on intelliJ.

Comment: Your code does produce the `Map` `{X=24, Y=25, Z=26}`. No errors.

Comment: if as you've said there is a compilation error then include the message within the post.

Comment: @Aominè some eclipse issue may be?

Comment: @Eugene I am using IntelliJ but yeah possibly...

Comment: @Aominè well obviously was not referring to you :)

Comment: Eran / @Aominè : Yes. Looks its a eclipse issue. Working fine on intelliJ. Thank you.

Comment: @PrasadChaudhari thanks to Eugene for mentioning eclipse, I never use it nor think of it in scenarios like this but yeah glad it helped :).

Comment: It works fine : https://ideone.com/qIc4Ns

Comment: What compiler compliance are you using and against which JRE is this being compiled?

Comment: @nitind verified.  Compliance and JRE both are set to correct java version. Java 8 here.

Comment: And which *version* of Eclipse is involved?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to uppercase the chars (if input is small case). Add the following and your code should run fine:

```
.map(Character::toUpperCase)
```

An another approach:

```
Map<Character, Integer> intArray = "xyz".chars()
                            .map(Character::toUpperCase)
                            .collect(HashMap::new,
                                (c,m) -> c.put((char)m,
                                 m-64),HashMap<Character,Integer>::putAll
                            );
```

Output:

```
{X=24, Y=25, Z=26}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the reason for the exception

Comment: @Pankaj : Code snippet provided in my post, how to incorporate this toUpperCase

Comment: Add it after .Chars(). Refer to the another approach I mentioned in my answer